# CSS fluid width centered images with off screen areas

Tags: css, responsive

[image]

Hi guys. Any ideas on how the layout in the diagram can be accomplished? 3 images of equal width, with the middle image centered in the viewport, and having a maximum width of 1200px.

The other two side images appear partially of screen.

As the browser window shrinks below 1200px, the center image fills the screen and scales down with the width of the window.

Am stumped at best way to achieve this with CSS alone!

Thanks!

Comment: Are these *actual* image or background images.

Comment: they could be either as long as the final effect is achieved!

Comment: Is this static or will the images move?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` and `justify-content` along `max-width`.

*animation on `:hover` and `shadow` is added to the sample to show behavior*

```css
#layout {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#layout img {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* demo purpose */

#layout {
  border: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}

#layout img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

#layout:hover img:first-of-type {
  animation: slide 6s infinite steps(3);
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-left: 200%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: -400%;
  }
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/food" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/people" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/fashion" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It's nearly exactly what I wanted, except that the height of the image does not scale in proportion when shrinking down. Also I would prefer not to use flex for better browser support (although I didn't mention this in the question so entirely my fault!). I have been experimenting since I posted and have  found another solution which I will post below

Comment: @Nick you can remove flex and add white-space:nowrap, then margin-left  on the first image will do . flex did the centering on itself. Here is  an example if you wish.  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XeXgOB break points can be added via mediaquerie also

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after some experimentation. The key was realising that at less than 1200 px the side images are not visible on screen at all, so can be hidden altogether - just making the center image 100%.

So wrapping all 3 images in a 3600px wide  absolutely positioned container and centering this with 50% left, margin-left -1800px;

At 1200 px and less, hiding image 2 and 3 altogether and making the container relatively positioned at 100% width.